# SVN operation time on Vista/Windows 7/2008 RC2

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

i have a problem. When i commit or update my project using Tortoise or AnkhSVN on operating systems mentioned in title, i have to wait very long time for operation to finish. While using Windows XP this problem doesn't occurs (of course i am using the same svn server :).

Do you know, what may cause this problem ?

ps. sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because those operating systems are IPv6 enabled. The timeout usually happens when a DNS lookup for the host succeeds, but the connection to it times out because it's not listening.

To fix this, you can either fix the DNS information to include just IPv4 addresses, or make IPv6 on the server work.

Can you indicate what kind of host (internet, intranet or localhost based) and protocol (http(s):// or svn://) you're using?

Comment: I'am using intranet and svn protocol. I'll try to fix DNS information tommorow :) Thx for reply!

Answer (score 0):

There may be some Antivirus or Windows Defender interference going on. In my experience, Subversion is slow on windows, regardless of client or version (including XP).

Comment: Sometimes having a Windows Explorer window open on a folder being updated by AnkhSVN can slowdown things considerable.  

(In this case TortoiseSVN's external cache process is continuously scanning the directory for changes...)